# no compatible gpus found for path tracing

Tags: gpu

No compatible gpus found for path tracing

- Intel core i7-2600 cpu 3.4
- memory ram: 22gb
- display: AMD radeon hd 5700 series 2gb
- Directx version:12

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have never heard of a 5750 or 5770 with 2GB of dedicated memory, and to be sure they never ever supported direct3d 12.

Answer (score 1):

The Radeon HD 5000 Series uses the old Terascale 2 architecture. [Blender 2.8 requires GCN second generation or newer for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd-opencl). Your graphics card is therefore not supported for GPU rendering.

Comment: That [error](https://github.com/lukeiwanski/tensorflow/issues/167#issuecomment-339420732) is [known](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/issues/218#issuecomment-351257403) to be [fixable](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/issues/1966) with the `GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR`/`GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT` environmental variables. Not sure why you felt like blacklisting older cards or drivers altogether (in fact, the only difference across gpu generations is probably just that newer ones come with more VRAM, which makes for a higher default chunk size)

Comment: @mirh I'm not sure what specific error you're referring to, there's nothing about memory allocation in this question? I personally haven't decided or done anything. Blender supports quite a range of hardware, but some older GPUs have iffy graphics driver or they don't support the OpenCL version that is required.