# Cycles - No compatible GPUs

Tags: cycles-render-engine

- Blender 2.83

  Windows 8.1 Pro

  CPU(s): E5-2690 (2)

  64GB RAM

  GeForce GTX Titan Black

  Nvidia Driver: 446.14

Any suggestions why I get the "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing" message when I chose CUDA for cycles?

The Titan Black is on the list (Compute 3.5).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

In this other thread there is a possible explanation. I have the same problem and I'm trying to fix it. Apparently it's because blender does not support older GPU cards arquitecture.

[no compatible gpus found for path tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151266/no-compatible-gpus-found-for-path-tracing)

Comment: That answer says it's because the card really was unsupported.  This is about a Titan Black card, which according to NVIDIA's stats has a compute capability of 3.5.   Blender claims to work with anything above 3, so, according to that it ought to work.

Comment: OK... sorry about that. Best of luck

Comment: Not a problem - you tried to help and posted a useful link, so thanks!  If you're not certain it solves the question asked, once you have the ability to comment that sort of "this might be helpful but I'm not certain" information is often (but not always) better as a comment.